# Change volume on a multi output device - Mac

Tags: mac, macbook-pro, audio, midi

;)
I have a small problem...
When creating a multi output device in the application "MIDI" on the mac, i don't have any problems at all. Now i want to make Videos (YouTube) and wanted to output the computer audio to the "Build in output" and to "Soundflower". It works fine, but the only problem is, that if i want to change the volume with the volume keys i can't because its locked (view Image).

So I went to google and searched for solutions and found the way to just change the volume on the different devices manually. But isn't there a easier solution?
I just want to be able to change the volume with the keys again and use that multi output device.

Greetings

PS: please don' mind my english because i am from Switzerland... ;)
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Press the volume-thingy on top in the menu after you hold the alt-button. You should be able to pick the source.

Comment: Thanks but i know how to change the in/out-put device. :)